# a sales tax on stonfi or dedust (The Open Network)

Tags: blockchain, telegram, smartcontracts, web3js, ton

Hi does anyone have any ideas on how a sales tax on jettons could be implemented in theory? i.e. if someone sells jettons on stonfi and takes a TON out of the pot I would like there to be some small tax on those taken out tons. Anybody have an idea how this could be done in theory?

I've tried to modify some recv function in jetton smart contract but I totally have no idea how to do that.